# Vulkan loading a texture in 8bit format is white in rendering

Tags: image, floating-point, vulkan

I'm loading a RGBA PNG picture into vulkan. I have no error during the process, but my shader shows me a white texture.

I quickly figured it out that if I multiply the sampled pixel by 0.00390625 (which is 1/256), I get back the right color. So in the process it seems vulkan just copy my 8bit value to a float version without converting it. what am I missing ?

I'm using a combined image sampler in GLSL and an image created with format VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UINT. I dont know where to tell Vulkan to convert data ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that when you create an image with the format `VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UINT`, the `UINT` suffix is explicitly telling Vulkan that you want the RGBA values to each appear in the shader as an 8-bit unsigned integer.

What you actually want is `VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM` instead.  The `UNORM` suffix tells Vulkan to take the 8 bits and convert them to a floating point value in the range of `[0, 1]`.

Most of the common formats have as possible suffixes

- `_UNORM` Converts the data to floating point in the range `[0, 1]`
- `_SNORM` Converts the data to floating point in the range `[-1, 1]`
- `_USCALED` Converts the data to floating point without changing the value
- `_SSCALED` Converts the data to floating point without changing the value (but treats the input as signed)
- `_UINT` Interprets the value as an unsigned integer
- `_SINT` Interprets the value as a signed integer

Additionally for formats that are wide enough to support floating point values, like `VK_FORMAT_R16G16B16A16_*` and `VK_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_*` then the suffix `_SFLOAT` is also available, telling Vulkan that the values in the channels are already floating point.  There's no `UFLOAT` because unsigned floats aren't supported.

9 times out of 10 when dealing with image data loaded out of some local file into an RGB buffer, you want the `_UNORM` version of whatever format you're sending to the driver in order to automatically scale the values to the appropriate floating point `[0, 1]` range.

Comment: I forgot about that, thx !